# Hardened UHF Antennas

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, uhf, history

Minuteman missile silos used an interesting hardened UHF antenna.
What kind of antenna is this? Does anyone have a drawing with a cross section?

[image: Hardened UHF Antenna]

**Edit:**

Jay Moore added a picture to a different type of hardened antenna, the truncated cone in the foreground.
[image: Different Antenna]
Jay's antenna might be an [annular slot antenna](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/60/jresv60n1p59_A1b.pdf), if it is an antenna and not another hatch. In that case, the lighter gray circle would be a dielectric. I don't think these are the same antenna types.

Comment: Some information about the UHF comm systems can be found here: https://minutemanmissile.com/uhfradio.html

Comment: In case anyone wonders, the MF antenna described on the page is an array of crossed folded dipoles. See here for more information: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0607419.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Amateur Radio! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I’m going to make a random guess that the top photo contains (at least) 2 antennas.  The annular slot on the cone is UHF or VHF, the tan circle around the cone is the annular slot of an HF antenna.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to find a complete answer, but have learned the following:

- the cone pictured in the top photo is a radome serving a weather protection function, not part of the antenna system.
- the UHF antenna is apparently a receive only antenna, used in the event of land system compromise
- the receiving antenna is atop a several feet thick concrete slab for protection
- some of these (not sure if all, or if the one pictured) were manufactured and perhaps designed by Motorola

Source:
https://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/mimi/hrs2-4.htm