# What is the minimum height required for a 60 meter NVIS antenna?

Tags: antenna-theory, hf, nvis

Various answers include 1/8th of the wavelength all the way down to 1/10th, but would 1/15th or even 1/20th of the wavelength be sufficient for a 60 meter (5 MHz) horizontal NVIS antenna?

Comment: You might find the answers to https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/746/how-to-determine-antenna-height-for-given-hf-frequency-and-coverage-radius?rq=1 useful

Comment: You didn't say *ideal* or *maximum* height for NVIS, which are both λ/4 high. [K2CG's answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/19988/8717) about loss vs. height is a good one. There is an NVIS myth propagating that says lower is always better. That's only good if the hams in your group are all close to each other *and* you want to limit how far away you can be heard.

Comment: OP's [related question with answers](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/does-a-nvis-antenna-have-to-be-exactly-below-the-maximum-nvis-frequency-to-have)

Answer (score 3):

Minimum height to accomplish what? It'll work right down to the ground, it'll just get lossier and lossier the lower you hang it. The exact numbers depend on your ground, and the threshold of "good enough" depends on you, your power, and who you're trying to talk to, so there's no real hard limit. Some unsourced internet numbers suggest that at 0.05 wavelength above ground you'll have about 6dB of additional loss compared to 0.2 wavelength above ground, which seems manageable.

Comment: People have used buried wires as clandestine antennas, so the minimum height above ground is negative, from a technical point of view.  Of course buried wires don't really make *practical* NVIS antennas...

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments for [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/hardened-uhf-antennas) includes a [link to a paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0607419.pdf) on blast-resistant ground level HF antenna's that the U.S. Airforce used or uses.  So zero.  Or negative if you count the buried cavity.